# How to change name servers ISNIC (DNS for .IS ccTLD)

Tags: dns, hosting, domain-name, nameservers, tld

How do you **change name servers** for your **.is domain** at [ISNIC](https://www.isnic.is/en/) ?

> In my case, the domain zipcode.is has the preconfigured DNS, pointing
>      to ISNIC domain-parking service `nserver:  parking00.isnic.is` and it
>      seems pretty hard/confusing to change it. Apparently, no sign of how 
>      to actually change the DNS in their [documentation](https://www.isnic.is/en/faq#q49).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-
**Step 1.**

Register your Name Servers at ISNIC - **Menu > Nameservers > [Register](https://www.isnic.is/en/host/new)**

- **Hostname is your Nameserver** e.g. NS1.YATKO.COM (in my case)
- **Zone Contact (NIC)** is your username, **find it in [My Settings](https://www.isnic.is/en/contact/change)**

***you may run into issues** like `Nameserver NS1.YATKO.COM  does not appear to comply with ISNIC's technical requirements` and you’ll need to **add PTR records to your DNS zone**

-
**Step 2.**

If you managed to get trough Step 1. then **Check domain setup with [ISNIC’s tool](https://www.isnic.is/en/domain/test)**, where simply **disregard ISP**, enter your Domain name, Master nameserver (e.g. NS1. …) and Nameserver 2, 3, … .

-
**Step 2.1**

You will likely get an error like this:

```
Test results for “NS1.YATKO.COM”:
No NS records found for domain ZIPCODE.IS on nameserver …
Test results for “NS2.YATKO.COM”:
No NS records found for domain ZIPCODE.IS on nameserver …
```

**Fix it by adding the DNS Zone** to your server. On a cPanel server, this **means creating a new account** (where you’re using your own name servers as NS1 and NS2, …).

-
**Step 3.**

**Go to Contacts > [My Page](https://www.isnic.is/en/contact/my)** and **under My domains check the domain you wish to modify**. The list to the right becomes active. **Select Web forwarding** and under Domain delegation **select Custom**. Change your Nameservers and Sumit.

> … no comment. If you dare to defend ISNIC’s solution, please do so. I am really curious how they invented the solution, and if anyone else in the world agrees with them :-)

Comment: One more thing, if all the above goes trough, changes to nameservers go to **queue pending verification** and the domain will be delegated when the request has been processed by ISNIC (manually). A five star to them for processing it on Sunday though!